# Why does Axes Tag resets after plotting in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axes

This is the hierarchy of my UI in MATLAB R2016a environment.

Figure->Panel->Axes

In order to retrieve the Axes within the panel I'm using `findobj` and `Tag` property.
When I plot for the first time no problem but as soon as I plot for the first time the `Axes` loses its `Tag` property, I don't understand why this is happening.

Is there any other way to retrieve axes info or can please explain to me why the axes are losing the Tag property?

Many thanks

Comment: Plotting resets most axes properties. You need to use [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) or, better yet, pass the handle of the axes object rather than relying on `findobj`.

Comment: @excaza it's seems to work I've never had this problem until R2014a. Seems graphics changed a lot since R2014b. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Nicholas There was a major update to the MATLAB graphics engine in the R2014b release. If you're curious see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/major-graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html